# How to properly configure OSSEC for Web Application Security ?

Tags: web-application, ids, intrusion

I would like to implement OSSEC as HIDS on my server, but by default OSSIC monitors a number of folders. I am going to deploy a web application on my server. So what should be my default OSSEC configuration for web application security  i.e. folders,logs to monitor for intrusion detection?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to include folders which contains your application. Should an attacker be able to exploit your server chances are they will write a file to your web root.

Comment: are you suggesting to monitor /var/www/html and my application is store in /usr/local? So should I store that too?  Another things how to detect if those file are robots or also some scaneer

Answer (score 0):

For intrusion detection you will definitely want to monitor your access.log and error.log files for this web app.  I would look out for:

1. Unusually high traffic.  Figure out what a normal amount of traffic is based on your access.log and set a monitor to alert you if you suddenly get a much greater amount (e.g. 10 times more requests) that could indicate either a DoS attack or server probing.
2. A large amount of POST requests.  This usually indicates a SQL injection attack.
3. Many lines in your error.log file.  Again this probably indicates server probing (or something misconfigured).

Others please feel free to add/edit.